# What's the most sensible way to do this in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a question which I think may have an easy answer. I have a numpy array with three dimensions - (num_users, num_dates, num_holdings). I'd like to initialize it to some random test values. random.rand works perfectly fine for this, but for each user and each date, the third dimension has to sum to 1 (ie, for any user and any date, their holdings have to sum to 1). I can do this by iterating, as in:

```
num_users = 2
num_dates = 2
num_holdings = 5

test_arr = np.random.rand(num_users, num_dates, num_holdings)

for user in range(num_users):
    for date in range(num_dates):
        starting_total = np.sum(test_arr[user, date, :])
        test_arr[user, date, :] = np.divide(test_arr[user, date, :], starting_total)

# Check it works
print(np.all(np.sum(test_arr, axis=2).reshape(-1)==1))
```

But if I'm creating multiple arrays it starts to get a bit slow. Plus it feels a little unsatisfactory. I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way to do it using vector math?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
test_arr /= test_arr.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True)
```

For example:

```
In [95]: test_arr = np.random.rand(2, 2, 5)

In [96]: test_arr
Out[96]: 
array([[[0.44621493, 0.04093414, 0.30051671, 0.40939041, 0.37251939],
        [0.33997017, 0.81257008, 0.52820553, 0.55382711, 0.11720684]],

       [[0.78460482, 0.43458619, 0.07722273, 0.18181153, 0.52101088],
        [0.47933417, 0.31354249, 0.09966921, 0.59655266, 0.24816989]]])

In [97]: test_arr.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True)
Out[97]: 
array([[[1.56957558],
        [2.35177973]],

       [[1.99923614],
        [1.73726842]]])
```

The use of `keepdims=True` means that we get a resulting shape (2,2,1) which will correctly broadcast when we divide by it.

```
In [98]: test_arr /= test_arr.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True)

In [99]: test_arr.sum(axis=2)
Out[99]: 
array([[1., 1.],
       [1., 1.]])
```

Note that because of limited precision you won't get *exactly* 1.0 as the sum, but the difference is negligible:

```
In [100]: test_arr.sum(axis=2) - 1.0
Out[100]: 
array([[ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [-1.11022302e-16, -1.11022302e-16]])
```

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't seen that keepdims parameter before, but I can imagine using it a lot in future.